# Redshift.DataLoadFailed when writing from Firehose into Redshift

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using a Lambda function to write data into Firehose then to Redshift. Problem is I get

> Redshift.DataLoadFailed: Loading data into the table failed. Check STL_LOAD_ERRORS system table for details

When I look into the details, its because

> Delimiter not found

When I look into the S3 bucket, I see my data writen in 1 long line ... is that supposed to be the case? I suspect thats the problem?

> "S77","2018-05-21T00:05:00+08:00","0""S109","2018-05-21T00:05:00+08:00","0""S117","2018-05-21T00:05:00+08:00","0"

I think I should see something like:

> "S77","2018-05-21T00:05:00+08:00","0"
>
> "S109","2018-05-21T00:05:00+08:00","0"
>
> "S117","2018-05-21T00:05:00+08:00","0"

Is that right? Did I do something wrong in my writing to Redshift?

```
firehose.putRecordBatch({
    DeliveryStreamName: 'raincover-nea-rainfall',
    Records: chunks[0].map(item => {
        console.log(item) // Something like: "S118","2018-05-21T00:10:00+08:00","0"
        return { 
            Data: item
        }
    })
}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('FAILED TO ADD CHUNK', err.message)
        return //reject(err)
    }
    console.log('CHUNK ADDED')
    console.log(data)
    //resolve(data)
})
```

Comment: Need more info, what are your COPY options in Firehose? What does it actually say in stl_load_errors? Looking again at what you have, it is appearing like you do not have end-of-line characters added to your data.

Comment: @TonyGibbs copy options is blank and i thought that putRecordBatch will add EOLs?